# track the items that are in the inventory

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a database that is tracking medical samples, you can think of each sample like a unique serial number.

The design: I have 3 tables (Inventory, InventoryTransactions, Manifests).
please see the attaced photo.

[image]

Inventory: has all the items and their properties either we have it right now or had it before, you can think of it as products.

Manifests: It records the transfer of multiple blocks at once from a place to another place and it records the type of movement(Transfer, Sale, Return,Received, Replacement) you can think of it as orders.
(Transfer and Received) mean that this SKU is in the company, but (sale, return, Replacement) mean that this SKU is going outside.

Inventory transaction is the conjunction table between the two tables which relates which SKU is transfered in which Manifest, You can think of it as OrderDetails.

example : we have item 1A we received at manifest m1, then transfered to another warehouse in the company in manifest m2, then sold to a customer in manifest m3.

What I want is that I want to query the items that is in hand right now, In any warehouse of the company, but as you see in my example if the where clause is movement = 'received' or movement = 'transfer')
doesn't give me correct information because the SKU maybe sold later.

I have an idea for a solution: which pulls the latest movement for an SKU and if it's not going outside the company we can assume it's "in" the company. but I think this is a flawed solution.

This is a MS Access Database, but I am familiar with SQL Statements, I want to know how logically this can be achieved. 
sorry for my English. I hope I have expressed myself right.

**Update:** This is My solution

```
SELECT Inventory.ID, Last(Manifests.MovementID) AS Lmove
FROM Manifests INNER JOIN (Inventory INNER JOIN InventoryTransactions ON Inventory.ID = InventoryTransactions.SKUID) ON Manifests.ID = InventoryTransactions.ManifestID
GROUP BY Inventory.ID
HAVING (((Last(Manifests.MovementID))<>2 And (Last(Manifests.MovementID))<>3 And (Last(Manifests.MovementID))<>5));
```

where 2,3,5 is the outgoing movements IDs

The expected result is all the items that we received but didn't sell yet.
here some samples from every table 
"Inventory"

```
SKU
TS-15 - 0415-A
```

"InventoryTransactions"

```
SKUID   ManifestID
TS-15 - 0415-A  NHSBC 1316 081915
TS-15 - 0415-A  Medimmune (PO # A-20190)
```

"Manifests"

```
ID  MovementID
NHSBC 1316 081915   Received
Medimmune (PO # A-20190)    Sale
```

In this sample "TS-15 - 0415-A" is received in the manifest "NHSBC 1316 081915" and then sold at the manifest "Medimmune (PO # A-20190)"
the ideal result shouldn't include "TS-15 - 0415-A" i the query because right now it's sold, therefore we don't have it in our inventory.

Comment: Pleas tag only the dbms you really workin on and read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: deleted the other dbms. I have just read the article, but really I couldn't add or delete to my question. I think this is the simplest form

Comment: Start by adding sample data,what you try so far and the expected resault.

Comment: Since you are using MsAccess, at least try to create the Query.  Then Choose the option that says "SQL", which will display the actual underlying SQL Query.  Paste that here, so that it be be tweaked / assisted to give you what you need.

Comment: Why do you think that solution is flawed?

Comment: Please go back and read [mcve] and then supply one. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/3404097

Comment: thank you for your comments, I am sorry about my poor formating of the question.
I have add a sample and the sql statement I am using.

Comment: please tell me if  I am going in the right direction to write MCVE

Comment: did I mess the thread completely, I hope there still a chance someone can help me even with a thought